# Understanding references: why this Numpy assignment is not working?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a little test code like so:

```
import numpy as np

foo = np.zeros(1, dtype=int)
bar = np.zeros((10, 1), dtype=int)


foo_copy = np.copy(foo)
bar[-1] = foo_copy

foo_copy[-1] = 10

print(foo_copy)
print(bar)
```

I was expecting both `foo_copy` and the last element of `bar` to contain the value 10, but instead the last element of `bar` is still an np array with value 0 in it.

```
[10]
[[0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]]  # <<--- why not 10?
```

Isn't that last element pointing to `foo_copy`?

Or in all assignments np will copy the data over and I can't change it by using the original ndarray?

If so, is there a way to keep that last element as a pointer to foo_bar?

Comment: `numpy.ndarray`'s **do not keep pointers**. That is *their entire purpose*, to provide efficient, fast, implementions of true multidimensional arrays of *primitive numerical values*. You maybe could hack something together with by using `dtype=object`, which basically means the dtype is PyObject pointers, although, you really probably shouldn't. If this is the case, you should *pretty much just use a regular python list* because a `numpy` array with dtype=object is pretty much a less efficient python list.

Comment: IOW, why are you using an array, when you want list semantics?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this was just a canonical example, in my code I actually do need the high performance but was not clear on this. Do you want to move it as an answer? Then I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: But then you will **lose the high performance of numpy** That performance comes from not using pointers to Python objects. If you use pointers to Python objects, then you again just have a less efficient Python list. In any case, there was another question I could have sworn I'd seen that explained this well in detail, trying to find it to provide it as a duplicate target

Comment: The **high performance** in `numpy` comes from using compiled methods.  Those mostly work with numeric dtypes such as `int`.  You may need to (re)read the `numpy` basics that focus on how arrays are stored.  The elements of `bar` are ints, not arrays (or lists).

Comment: Right, thanks - I wanted to understand this correctly which I think I did now. I will change my code to conform to how NumPy works instead of insisting on this structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `numpy` array have numeric values, not references (at least for numeric `dtypes`):

Make a 1d array, and reshape it to 2d:

```
In [64]: bar = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
In [65]: bar
Out[65]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

Another 1d array:

```
In [66]: foo = np.array([10])
In [67]: foo
Out[67]: array([10])
```

This assignment is by value:

```
In [68]: bar[1,1] = foo
In [69]: bar
Out[69]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3, 10,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

So is this, though the values are `broadcasted` to the whole row:

```
In [70]: bar[2] = foo
In [71]: bar
Out[71]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3, 10,  5],
       [10, 10, 10],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

We can `view` the 2d array as 1d.  This is closer representation of how the values are actually stored (but in a `c` byte array, 12*8 bytes long):

```
In [72]: bar1 = bar.ravel()
In [73]: bar1
Out[73]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3, 10,  5, 10, 10, 10,  9, 10, 11])
```

Changing an element of `view` changes the corresponding element of the 2d:

```
In [74]: bar1[3] = 30
In [75]: bar
Out[75]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [30, 10,  5],
       [10, 10, 10],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

While we can make `object` dtype arrays, which store references as lists do, they do not have any performance benefits.

The bytestring containing the 'raw data' of `bar`:

```
In [76]: bar.tobytes()
Out[76]: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

The fabled `numpy` speed comes from working with this raw data with compiled `c` code.  Accessing individual elements with the Python code is relatively slow.  It's the whole-array operations like `bar*3` that are fast.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very useful.